# No wifi and display brightness options after removing Nvidia graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, brightness, iwlwifi

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 few days ago. Everything was normal, but today I just installed NVIDIA graphic drivers as I have a graphics card in my laptop and then during rebooting I encountered with black screen and with a blinking cursor (no login screen), so I uninstalled the drivers using `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia`. I got the login screen back, but now I do not have any wifi option and also no brightness option.

Laptop details:

- HP pavilion 15-cs3073cl.
- Vendor:Intel Corporation
- Product: Ice Lake-LP CNVi WiFi
- GPU:NVIDIA GeForce MX250

I do not have access to Ethernet internet.

**Edit**

Booted from previous kernel (5.15) and both WiFi and brightness works normally.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

`00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:34f0] (rev 30) DeviceName: Intel Wireless-WiFi 6 AX201 Dual Band 2x2 WiFi + BT 5  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:0074] Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi`

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel and check. I think it is not related to Nvidia drivers.

Comment: How to boot with previous kernel? Ithink it is related to drivers because Wi-Fi was working normally before. After removing nvidia drivers it doesn't appear

Comment: Use grub menu..

Comment: Booted from previous kernel (5.15) and both wifi and brightness works normally. How to make this kernel default?

Comment: The goal is not to make this kernel default, but to solve the problem. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: This device should be supported. Probably you accidentally removed some kernel modules. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally removed some kernel packages when ran a wrong `apt-get remove --purge nvidia` command.

Run

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

and reboot. It should fix issues with the modules.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution worked perfectly and fixed my issue.
How can I now install NVIDIA drivers to avoid any kind of issues?

Comment: Run `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. Also you need either disable Secure Boot, or enroll a MOK key.